# how to make the foot cover entire width of the page in ionic 3

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

In the image below, I want the indicator such as normal etc to cover the entire width of the page. i want the indicator to be smooth and not have any white spaces. the background should also be transparent. now its showing something like a whitish color. I am using ionic 3 and angular 4.
    my .css page

```
.map_legend{
  background: transparent !important;
    .legend_title{
        margin: 4px;
        font-size:  1.0rem;
    }
    ul.legend_list{
       margin: 4px;
       padding: 0px;

        li{
            display:inline-block;
            margin-right: -4px;
            .legend_values{
                color:#ffffff; 
                padding: 7px; 
                font-size: 1.2rem;
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                bottom: 0px;
                left: 0px;
            }
        }
    }
   }
my .html
      <div class="map_legend">

    <span class="legend_title" style="color: black;">{{"Heat Wave Alert" | 
translate}}</span>
    <ul class="legend_list"> 

      <li><span class="legend_values" style="background:green;">{{"Normal" | 
translate}}</span></li>
      <li><span class="legend_values" style="background:yellow; color: 
#333;">{{"Caution" | translate}}</span></li>
      <li><span class="legend_values" style="background:red;">{{"Extreme 
Caution" | translate}}</span></li>
      <li><span class="legend_values" style="background:black;">{{"No 
Forecast" | translate}}</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ONHG.png)

Comment: please add al working code link. thanks

Comment: the above code is just for the part that i need i.e the indicators with textboxes not the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added your `span` `css` to `li`, width: `width: -webkit-fill-available;` for chrome ,`width: -moz-available;` for firefox and `display: flex` to ul

```css
.map_legend {
  background: transparent !important;
}

.map_legend .legend_title {
  margin: 4px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.map_legend ul.legend_list {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.map_legend ul.legend_list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  bottom: 0px;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  width: -moz-available;
}
```

```html
<div class="map_legend">

  <span class="legend_title" style="color: black;">{{"Heat Wave Alert" | 
translate}}</span>
  <ul class="legend_list">

    <li style="background:green;"><span class="legend_values">Normal
</span></li>
    <li style="background:yellow; color: 
#333;"><span class="legend_values">Caution</span></li>
    <li style="background:red;"><span class="legend_values">Extreme 
Caution</span></li>
    <li style="background:black;"><span class="legend_values">No 
Forecast</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```